# Python Checking a string's first and last character

Tags: python, string, python-2.7

can anyone please explain what is wrong with this code?

```
str1='"xxx"'
print str1
if str1[:1].startswith('"'):
    if str1[:-1].endswith('"'):
        print "hi"
    else:
        print "condition fails"
else:
    print "bye"
```

The output I got is:

```
Condition fails
```

but I expected it to print `hi` instead.

Answer (score 120, accepted):

When you say `[:-1]` you are stripping the last element. Instead of slicing the string, you can apply `startswith` and `endswith` on the string object itself like this

```
if str1.startswith('"') and str1.endswith('"'):
```

So the whole program becomes like this

```
>>> str1 = '"xxx"'
>>> if str1.startswith('"') and str1.endswith('"'):
...     print "hi"
>>> else:
...     print "condition fails"
...
hi
```

Even simpler, with a conditional expression, like this

```
>>> print("hi" if str1.startswith('"') and str1.endswith('"') else "fails")
hi
```

Answer (score 33):

You should either use

```
if str1[0] == '"' and str1[-1] == '"'
```

or

```
if str1.startswith('"') and str1.endswith('"')
```

but not slice and check startswith/endswith together, otherwise you'll slice off what you're looking for...

Comment: You're accidentally using = instead of ==.

Answer (score 16):

You are testing against the string **minus the last character**:

```
>>> '"xxx"'[:-1]
'"xxx'
```

Note how the last character, the `"`, is not part of the output of the slice.

I think you wanted just to test against the last character; use `[-1:]` to slice for just the last element.

However, there is no need to slice here; just use `str.startswith()` and `str.endswith()` directly.

Answer (score 0):

When you set a string variable, it doesn't save quotes of it, they are a part of its definition.
so you don't need to use :1